# How do I check if an IP is alive in java?

Tags: java, sockets, ip, port, host

There are 5 devices in my network with different IP addresses. I wish to connect to these devices and get data from them over TCP/IP socket when they are available in my network. 
How can I check if they are available in java?

```
public void setUpConnection() {
    try {
        Socket client = new Socket(hostIp, hostPort);
        socketReader = client.getInputStream();
        socketWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection: unknown host at " +   hostIp);
        System.out.println("host: " + hostIp + "port: " + hostPort);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection: " + e);
        System.out.println("host: " + hostIp + "port:" + hostPort);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can open a Socket connect to each host to determine if that port is available.

Answer (score 19):

```
InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut);
```

Further reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to check whether or not the host is up, you can use [isReachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

For pure Java there are basically two methods:

1. Active: as your example, but looping thru all ports and all bound IP's on the host
2. Passive: running a small server on predefined port(s) and the other one will register  themself when they get available.

isReachable may fail for a lot of reasons as stated in the docs.

Comment: These are all my device's host and port: 1- 192.168.30.190:3001 2- 192.168.30.191:3001 3- 192.168.30.192:3001 4- 192.168.30.193:3001 5- 192.168.30.194:3001 Could you please give a sample of Passive way?

Comment: If your devices config is a fix set, then write some thread that tries to connect with timeout to each of them as your example. For all other setups (host/ip/port detection) IMHO you need a DHCP server because pure Java don´t reach the network layers to do this in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP is a mode of handshaking. To make connection with any of these 5 devices. both your client and the recipient client should be alive. First if possible then use **Socket NIO**. can you write client logic such that whenever any of client comes online first make an entry of its ip and port in database and try to get other available ip and ports from database and try to create connection with them. whenever any client device became unreachable delete that entry from database. Example: *when first device comes online then there is only one socket will be created because there is only one entry in databae when second device comes online there is two entries one is the ip and port of this device and the second entry belong to the device which came first.*

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: Is this good? Can i relay on it?
public boolean hostAvailabilityCheck(){
        boolean available = true;
        try {
            (new Socket(host, port)).close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // unknown host
            available = false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // io exception, service probably not running
            available = false;
        }
        return available;
    }